# Change window background using SetClassLongPtr

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I have a drop-down menu that I want to use to change the background of my window; the window is defaulted at my "Winter background".

```
wClass.hbrBackground = CreatePatternBrush(LoadBitmap(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(WinterBG)));
```

Whenever an item in the drop-down menu is chosen, it sets off CBN_SELCHANGE, where I grab the length and string of the item chosen. I want the background to change based on that.

```
case WM_COMMAND:
    {
        switch(HIWORD(wParam))
        {
        case CBN_SELCHANGE:
            {
                ItemIndex = SendMessage((HWND)lParam, (UINT)CB_GETCURSEL, (WPARAM)0, (LPARAM)0);
                int ItemLen = SendMessage((HWND)lParam, (UINT)CB_GETLBTEXTLEN, (WPARAM)0, (LPARAM)0);
                char* ListItem = (char*)malloc(ItemLen+1);
                (char)SendMessageA((HWND)lParam, (UINT)CB_GETLBTEXT, (WPARAM)ItemIndex, (LPARAM)ListItem);

                //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                // I am certain this can be optimized

                if ( ItemLen == 5 && ListItem[0] == 'S' ) // Spring
                {
                    MessageBox(NULL, L"Spring chosen", L"Confirmed", MB_ICONINFORMATION | MB_OK);
                    HBRUSH brush = CreatePatternBrush(LoadBitmap(wClass.hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(SpringBG)));
                    SetClassLongPtr(hWnd, GCLP_HBRBACKGROUND, (LONG)brush);
                    InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, TRUE);
                    UpdateWindow(hWnd);
                }
.....
```

SetClassLongPtr isn't working how I want it to. After updating the window (I read InvalidateRect & UpdateWindow achieve that), nothing changes--the background remains on my "WinterBG".

Am I using SetClassLongPtr correctly? If not, how else can I change the background?

Comment: The point of SetClassLongPtr over SetClassLong is that the 3rd argument is a LONG_PTR instead of a LONG.  Clearly your cast is incorrect.  Improve your error checking too.

Comment: Ouch... it was that simple.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried what you are trying to accomplish in a simple Win32 project and managed to make it work. To make the code below work, you need to make sure both bitmaps are present as a resource in your VC++ project.
I have defined two bitmaps as resources in my VC++ project. I am not using any menu as you do. I am processing the WM_KEYDOWN message, but the idea is the same, this should also work then under your WM_COMMAND message.
The code below does the following things:

1. Load the bitmap from the resource section of the exe file. It needs an HINSTANCE for this, which inside your WndProc you can get using GetWindowLongPtr (use this instead of GetWindowLong, especially when you are coding for 64-bit environments, see also Microsoft's note on this in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowlongw).
2. Create the new brush with the same function you used: 'CreatePatternBrush'.
3. Change the background of your window using this brush and store the returned old brush, so you can delete it afterwards. You do this using the SetClassLongPtr (same 64-bit note applies here). The confusing part may be the last parameter which is a LONG_PTR. This may seem like a pointer to the reader, but in fact it is a __int64 (64-bit integer).
4. Delete the old brush (to prevent memory leaks, especially if you expect to execute this code multiple times in a session).
5. Refresh your window by invalidating the entire client area (argument NULL) and setting the repaint argument to TRUE.

That should do it. Here is the section of my WndProc function that does this:

```
    case WM_KEYDOWN:
    switch (wParam)
    {
    case VK_F1:
        HINSTANCE hInst2 = (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_HINSTANCE);
        HBITMAP newBmp = LoadBitmapW(hInst2, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_BITMAP2));
        HBRUSH newBrush = (HBRUSH)CreatePatternBrush(newBmp);
        HBRUSH oldBrush = (HBRUSH)SetClassLongPtr(hwnd, GCLP_HBRBACKGROUND, (LONG_PTR)newBrush);
        DeleteObject(oldBrush);
        InvalidateRect(hwnd, NULL, TRUE);
        break;
    }
    break;
```

Small remark: The last 'break' in the code above is just because at the bottom of my WndProc the DefWindowProc is called. When processing a WM_KEYDOWN message in your WndProc, it should always be passed on to the DefWindowProc so it can be correctly handled by Windows. In your menu case this last 'break' statement could probably be replaced by 'return 0'.